# Rails Namespace vs. Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, routes, nested-resources

Let's say my app has two models, Foo and Bar.

Foo optionally belongs_to Bar.

Right now I can look at a single Foo, or search for a particular Foo, and the FoosController handles all that. My URLS are like:
`foos/1` and `foos/new`

Sometimes I want to look at a Bar. The BarsController handles that, and I get to it like:
`bars/1` or `bars/1/edit`.

If I'm looking at a Bar I might want to browse all the Foos that are part of that Bar. So, I'd like to use `bars/1/foos/` to look at those Foos.

This is pretty straightforward with nested resources, and it looks like this:

```
resources :foo
resources :bar do
  resources :foo
end
```

However, Foos that are part of a Bar are kind of special, set apart from regular Foos. So, for instance, if I load `foos/1` or `bars/1/foos/1`, I would be looking at the same Foo, but I am focused on different information in each case.

So I've been thinking about having a BarFoos Controller to handle Foos when they're in the context of a Bar. However, if I nest BarFoos under Bar, then my helpers are going to be like `bar_bar_foos_path` and `new_bar_bar_foo_path`. That seems redundant.

So, now I'm thinking about namespaces, which is something I've never looked into before. I see in the rails guide that I could define:

```
namespace "bar" do
  resources :foos
end
```

If I do that I can make a second `FoosController` under `app/bar/`, and that FoosController can handle Foos inside of a Bar with nice helpers like `bar_foo_path(:id)` instead of `bar_bar_foo_path(:id)`.

But if I do that, what happens to my `BarsController`? How do requests get routed to `BarsController` if instead of `resources :bars` I have `namespace "bar"`?

And, lastly, is there anything special I need to do inside my secondary FoosController to make sure there's not a name conflict with the top-level FoosController? I realize the routing says "namespace", but how does the rest of the ruby code know that the `app/bar/foos_controller` and `app/foos_controller` are not the same class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is:

1. Bar has many Foos
2. View Foos belonging to Bar
3. View all Foos regardless of parent.

You can achieve that with:
routes.rb:

```
resources :foos
resources :bars do
  resources :foos, :controller => 'bars/foos'
end
```

The route helpers you end up with are:

- bars_path
- foos_path
- bars_foos_path
- etc, etc, 'rake routes' for the rest 
  =)

In essence, you end up with:

- app/BarsController (rails g controller bars)
- app/FoosController (rails g controller foos)
- app/bars/FoosController (rails g controller bars/foos)

In FoosController, you would access foos as usual with:

```
@foos = Foos.all
```

and in bars/FoosController, you would access bar's foos with:

```
@foos = @bar.foos
```

where bar can be pre-retrieved in the bars/foos controller with:

```
before_filter :get_client

private
def get_client
  @bar = Bar.find(params[:bar_id])
end
```

Hope this helps. =)

**Edit**:
As for namespaced routes, I've personally used them when I some of my resources retrieved from a sub-path.  For example, if I have an admin section of my site, then I might have the following:

routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :foos
end
```

and I create my controller with:

```
rails g controller admin/foos
```

This sets up my foos resource, such that I can access it at "my site url"/admin/foos, and also get helpers such as admin_foos_path.

Comment: Your description of my scenario is exactly right, and your answer is very clear, thank you! I see how your answer would work, so that's awesome! Just to follow up on one detail, would you *recommend* nesting over namespacing in this scenario? Could you offer any pros/cons you've experienced either way?

Comment: In your case, because bar and foo are both resources, and foo belongs to bar, it makes perfect sense to use nested resources.  To expand upon the namespace explanation above: if you're in a situation where you're dealing with different behaviour for different contexts, i.e. if I'm admin, I do A, otherwise I do B, and the logic is anything but the simplest or scattered all over, then I will consider namespacing and add a controller to allow me to work in that specific context.  'admin' represent a context as opposed to a resource in this case.

Comment: Great, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 6):

There are cons to this approach.

If you declare a constant, eg. CONST_NAME, in nested resource `foos`, rails will throw "uninitialized constant ::Foo::CONST_NAME" exception because of its scope algorithm.

To avoid such behaviour, use:

```
resources :foos
resources :bars do
  scope :module => "bar" do
    resources :foos #, :controller => 'bar/foos' no need to use this now because route will be searched there by default
  end
end
```

Now you will not get an exception while using:

```
Foo::CONST_NAME
```

or

```
Bar::Foo::CONST_NAME
```